# (Macos) apt: not resolving jdk path

Tags: java, macos, cmake, apt

I spent most of the day yesterday searching for a clear solution for doing the following command

```
qu@QMACs-MacBook-Pro ~ % apt search cmake
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
qu@QMACs-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

I got the message above, what shall I do for this?

Comment: Did you mean to tag Java instead of JavaScript?

Comment: Whats the output of "java -version" ?

Comment: qu@QMACs-MacBook-Pro ~ % java --version
java 13.0.2 2020-01-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
qu@QMACs-MacBook-Pro ~ %

Comment: I wonder apt is a part of jdk natively. Check your path variables for jdk and apt.

Comment: How can i do that please, which commands shall i excute

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359219/error-when-using-apt-on-macos-sierra. There is no `apt` package manager on MacOS. Googling for "macos install cmake" shows most references about using `brew` package manager.

Comment: thanks a lot but when i install it i got this error Error: Failed to link all completions, docs and manpages:
  Permission denied @ rb_file_s_symlink - (../../../Homebrew/completions/zsh/_brew, /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew)
Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force
qusayqu@QMACs-MacBook-Pro ~ %

Answer (score 1):

Apt is not available for MacOS. There are other options such as Homebrew or Macports. It depends what version of linux you're using. Debian based distros use sudo apt-get  while Fedora based distros use yum install  .Dec 12, 2018